# Post request is not sending all variables

Tags: php, javascript, request, max

I have a form which consists of rows set up like:

```
<div class="row unit" onmouseover="this.style.background = '#eeeeee';" onmouseout="this.style.background = 'white';" onclick="if(event.srcElement.nodeName != 'INPUT' && event.srcElement.nodeName != 'SELECT' && event.srcElement.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA'){goToByScroll(event.srcElement,-160);}">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="select">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select<?php echo $i; ?>" name="select<?php echo $i; ?>">
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="col name">
                <p><input class="searchable" type="text" id="name<?php echo $i; ?>" name="name<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"></p>
                <p>Badge ID: <input class="searchable" type="text" id="badge<?php echo $i; ?>" name="badge<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $badge; ?>" style="width: 50px;"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col phone">
                <p>Work: <input class="searchable" type="text" id="phone<?php echo $i; ?>" name="phone<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"></p>
                <p>Cell: <input class="searchable" type="text" id="cell<?php echo $i; ?>" name="cell<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $cell; ?>"></p>
                <p>Home: <input class="searchable" type="text" id="home<?php echo $i; ?>" name="home<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $home; ?>"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col email">
                <p>Work: <input class="searchable" type="text" id="email<?php echo $i; ?>" name="email<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></p>
                <p>Personal: <input class="searchable" type="text" id="perEmail<?php echo $i; ?>" name="perEmail<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $perEmail; ?>"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col file">
                <p class="removeFile"><input type="text" id="filename<?php echo $i; ?>" name="filename<?php echo $i; ?>" class="file" value="<?php echo $filename; ?>" readonly>
                Remove: <input type="checkbox" id="removeFile<?php echo $i; ?>" name="removeFile<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
                <input type="file" id="file<?php echo $i; ?>" name="file<?php echo $i; ?>" onchange="myForm.elements['filename<?php echo $i; ?>'].value=myForm.elements['file<?php echo $i; ?>'].value;">
            </div>
</div>
```

These rows get repeated using a javascript function which increments the name:

```
function addTableRow(table){
    for(i=0; i<myForm.elements['entriesNum'].value; i++){
        var $tr = $(table).find(".row:last").clone();
        $tr.find("input,select,textarea").attr("name", function(){
          var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
          return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
        }).attr("id", function(){
          var parts = this.id.match(/(\D+)(\d+)$/);
          return parts[1] + ++parts[2];
        });
        $(table).find(".row:last").after($tr);

        $tr.find('.fileElements').remove();
        $tr.find('input[type!="radio"], textarea').removeAttr("value");
        $tr.find('input').removeAttr("checked");
        $tr.find('select option:first-child').attr("selected", true);
        $tr.find('input[type!="radio"]').removeAttr("disabled");
        $tr.find('input[type="radio"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $tr.find('.error').hide();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly until the number of rows gets higher than 111. At this point when I submit no more data gets included in the array no matter how many rows I add. I was able to deduce this by using print_r($_REQUEST);. I have edited my php.ini and set all the maxes to be absurdly high with still no change.

Comment: Did you restart apache after editing php.ini?

Comment: I think you really should be using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` if your jQuery version is newer than 1.6. Can't say whether it's your problem or not.

Comment: Are you using a hardedned version of php such as suhosin or hardened-php?

Comment: @Pointy It doesn't matter. Versions greater than 1.6 suport `.attr()` too

Comment: I am not using apache I am using IIS. I have restarted after each edit. I'm using PHP 5.3 from the PHP website.

Comment: @asprin  yes that's true but there are two methods for a reason :-) They're not exactly the same.  For properties of DOM elements it's better practice to use `.prop()`.

Comment: I figured it out. I never removed the ; from in front of max_input_vars. This solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I've had issues with javascript created form elements not showing up in the POST, it's always had to do with the way I've structured the FORM tags.

Things to look for...

Is your FORM tag properly closed off?

Is your FORM start and close at the same level in the DOM?  For example, you wouldn't want to do this...

```
<form method='post'>
<div>
  <!--lots of stuff-->
  </form>
</div>
```

You would instead want this...

```
<form method='post'>
  <div>
    <!--lots of stuff-->
  </div>
</form>
```

Do you have another FORM tag that's opened and not closed before the one you're actually working with?  Like this...

```
<form method='get'>
   <!--some kind of form about something else-->

<form method='post'>
   <!--the data you're currently focused on-->
</form>
```

Comment: I suck and just noticed your comment about data not showing up only after reaching a certain number of rows.  So this wouldn't apply.

Dang it!  Every time I try and give back to this site that's given me so much I blow it! :-)